# SQLAlchemy type decorator fails with `object has no attribute 'self_group'`

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a legacy Python 3 codebase using SQLAlchemy 1.1 which, for "reasons", has a class:

```
class jsonbool(str):
   def __bool__(self):
       return True if self == 'true' else False
```

This class is used in a SQLAlchemy filter expression, e.g. `query.filter(SomeTable.ABooleanColumn == anInstanceOfjsonbool).all()`. This worked fine in 1.1, as the string representation of the `jsonbool` type was used (e.g. `true` or `false`).

In SQLAlchemy 1.2, additional checking has been added on their side to prevent the cooercion of some types to booleans. What worked above now fails with `sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.TypeError) Not a boolean value: 'false'` (the `false` there is actually an instance of `jsonbool`).

I thought to correct this with a SQLAlchemy TypeDecorator, which would allow me to convert the parameter to a boolean when bound in an expression. My prototype was just to get custom type decoration working, with:

```
import sqlalchemy.types as types

class jsonbool(str, types.TypeDecorator):
   impl = types.Boolean

   def __bool__(self):
       return True if self == 'true' else False
```

Alas, this, and everything similar I try results in `AttributeError: 'Boolean' object has no attribute 'self_group'` (where `s/Boolean/WhateverImplIPick`) when attempting to run a query. I have also tried using a `UserDefinedType` with the same result.

How can I change the behaviour of the `jsonbool` type when I'm using it as part of SQLAlchemy expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `TypeDecorator` is a SQLAlchemy type, akin to `String` or `Boolean`, instances of which are used to declare the type of a column or expression, as in

```
foo = Column(String, ...)
bar = Column(jsonbool, ...)
```

Using such a type as a value makes no sense, so just as how `str` is separate from `String`, you need a `JsonBool` class separate from `jsonbool`, like this:

```
class JsonBool(TypeDecorator):
    impl = Boolean

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        return value == "true"

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        return jsonbool("true") if value else jsonbool("false")
```

Of course, you'll need to change the definition of your `SomeTable.ABooleanColumn` to use this type:

```
ABooleanColumn = Column(JsonBool, ...)
```

This might be a tall order for your code base, in which case you can make SQLAlchemy do [custom compilation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/compiler.html) for `jsonbool` objects:

```
class jsonbool(str, ColumnElement):
    def __bool__(self):
        return True if self == 'true' else False

@compiles(jsonbool)
def _compile_jsonbool(element, compiler, **kwargs):
    if element:
        return compiler.visit_true(None)
    else:
        return compiler.visit_false(None)
```

Comment: Looks like I entirely misunderstood the notion of a Type/TypeDecorator. Thanks so much!